# Find The Pattern To Get This Script

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get data from this script. This script was taken from the other HTML.
The script :

```
<script>_bwaq.push(['_trackBanner','a8e8a960d7184aaa8b7194bb2b34ded3','banner','open','cf650f6fde0dca38be8da6a41e47e9ac']);addToPendingOnloadBwa(['_trackProductView','733380','-1002']);var landingPageURL=window.location;var vizLayer={type:'product_page',pid:'733380',pname:'Apple iPhone 6 64 GB Silver Smartphone',lp:landingPageURL,image:'https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/full/good-guys_apple-iphone-6-64-gb-silver-smartphone_full01.jpg',availability:'true',currency:'IDR',newprice:'10610000',oldprice:"",catid:"54593",catname:"Handphone & Tablet",subcatid:"54611",subcatname:"Handphone",subsubcatid:"54614",subsubcatname:"iPhone",pdesc:'',inventory:'',brand:'Brand{name=Apple, url=apple, anchor=false}',color:'',size:'',prodrating:'',numratings:''};</script>
```

I want to get data from variable vizLayer?
What is the pattern regex to get data vizLayer? And i want to split or explode each row value. i want to get data specific like :

> pname = Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime SM-G530H Putih Smartphone [8 GB],
>   newprice = 2425000, 
>   oldprice =2699000, availability = true

Anyone got any ideas to get Pattern Regex? And how to explode?

Comment: `vizLayer.pname`, `vizLayer.oldprice` and `vizLayer.availability`, no need of regex here

Comment: Sorry, I forget to explain. This script was taken from the other HTML.  @Tushar

Comment: @Robby Wijaya-can you confirm the script always contain tags in following order pname,lp,image,availability,currency,newprice,oldprice?

Comment: @RobbyWijaya Please give somemore context: what ist the exact input (type and value)? What is the desired output? what have you tried until now?